# How do I get started using BouncyCastle?

Tags: cryptography, bouncycastle

So after [CodingHorror's fun with encryption](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001267.html) and the thrashing comments, we are reconsidering doing our own encryption.

In this case, we need to pass some information that identifies a user to a 3rd party service which will then call back to a service on our website with the information plus a hash.

The 2nd service looks up info on that user and then passes it back to the 3rd party service.

We want to encrypt this user information going into the 3rd party service and decrypt it after it comes out.  So it is not a long lived encryption.

On the coding horror article, Coda Hale recommended BouncyCastle and a high level abstraction in the library to do the encryption specific to a particular need.

My problem is that the BouncyCastle namespaces are huge and the documentation is non-existant.  Can anyone point me to this high level abstraction library?  (Or another option besides BouncyCastle?)

Comment: RECONSIDERING writing your own encryption lib?  Good choice!

Comment: Although there's not a lot of documentation with BouncyCastle, I find their mailing list very helpful http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharpdevmailarchive/index.html. You can also subscribe to ask questions. 

You should also get the source it comes with examples and tests, which cover most use cases.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a typical use-case for OAuth - have you considered using that?

Comment: @NickJohnson although OAuth was technically around when I asked this question - it wasn't formalized and certainly wasn't widely known. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#History

Comment: Marking this as "not constructive" is... not constructive. BouncyCastle is a mess of undocumented interfaces that make no sense to a human observer.Asking for a practical approach to get started is the the most constructive thing a person can ask for in this case. I understand why this site has standards, but standards shouldn't get in the way of real life.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

High level abstraction? I suppose the highest level abstractions in the Bouncy Castle library would include:

- The [BlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/BlockCipher.html) interface (for symmetric ciphers)
- The [BufferedBlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/BufferedBlockCipher.html) class
- The [AsymmetricBlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/AsymmetricBlockCipher.html) interface
- The [BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher.html) class
- The [CipherParameters](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/CipherParameters.html) interface (for initializing the block ciphers and asymmetric block ciphers)

I am mostly familiar with the Java version of the library. Perhaps this code snippet will offer you a high enough abstraction for your purposes (example is using AES-256 encryption):

```
public byte[] encryptAES256(byte[] input, byte[] key) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    assert key.length == 32; // 32 bytes == 256 bits
    CipherParameters cipherParameters = new KeyParameter(key);

    /*
     * A full list of BlockCiphers can be found at http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/BlockCipher.html
     */
    BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();

    /*
     * Paddings available (http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/paddings/BlockCipherPadding.html):
     *   - ISO10126d2Padding
     *   - ISO7816d4Padding
     *   - PKCS7Padding
     *   - TBCPadding
     *   - X923Padding
     *   - ZeroBytePadding
     */
    BlockCipherPadding blockCipherPadding = new ZeroBytePadding();

    BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher, blockCipherPadding);

    return encrypt(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters);
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, CipherParameters cipherParameters) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    boolean forEncryption = true;
    return process(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters, forEncryption);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, CipherParameters cipherParameters) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    boolean forEncryption = false;
    return process(input, bufferedBlockCipher, cipherParameters, forEncryption);
}

public byte[] process(byte[] input, BufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher, CipherParameters cipherParameters, boolean forEncryption) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
    bufferedBlockCipher.init(forEncryption, cipherParameters);

    int inputOffset = 0;
    int inputLength = input.length;

    int maximumOutputLength = bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(inputLength);
    byte[] output = new byte[maximumOutputLength];
    int outputOffset = 0;
    int outputLength = 0;

    int bytesProcessed;

    bytesProcessed = bufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(
            input, inputOffset, inputLength,
            output, outputOffset
        );
    outputOffset += bytesProcessed;
    outputLength += bytesProcessed;

    bytesProcessed = bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(output, outputOffset);
    outputOffset += bytesProcessed;
    outputLength += bytesProcessed;

    if (outputLength == output.length) {
        return output;
    } else {
        byte[] truncatedOutput = new byte[outputLength];
        System.arraycopy(
                output, 0,
                truncatedOutput, 0,
                outputLength
            );
        return truncatedOutput;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Whoops, I just read the article you linked to. It sounds like he is talking about even higher level abstractions than I thought (e.g., "send a confidential message"). I am afraid I don't quite understand what he is getting at.

Comment: Thanks for checking out the article... it would be nice to have a library like what he is describing as the uses for encryption are many and the misuses are even greater.

Comment: +1 for effort but not really an answer i can use.

Comment: Adam Paynter also have a look at my question. I simply want to encrypt text using chcacha20 . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050559/illegalargumentexception-chacha20-requires-128-bit-or-256-bit-key

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you write your application in Java I'd recommend that you don't use a specific provider, but that you develop your application on top of Sun's JCE (Java Cryptography Extension). Doing so can make you independent of any underlying providers, I.e., you can switch providers easily as long as you use ciphers that are widely implemented. It does give you a certain level of abstraction as you don't have to know all the details of the implementations and may protect you a little from using the wrong classes (e.g. such as using raw encryption without proper padding etc) Furthermore, Sun provides a decent amount of documentation and code samples.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually found that this sample uses default 128 bit encryption instead of 256 bit. I've made a little change:

```
BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();
```

now becomes:

```
BlockCipher blockCipher = new RijndaelEngine(256);
```

and it works together with my client application C++ AES256 encryption

Answer (score 2):

One example of a high(er)-level API in BouncyCastle would be the CMS ([Cryptographic Message Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax)) package. This ships in a separate jar (bcmail) from the provider itself, and is written to the JCE (The C# version is written against the lightweight API however).

"Send a confidential message" is implemented, roughly speaking, by the CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator class, and all you really need to do is give it the message, choose an encryption algorithm (all details handled internally), and then specify one or more ways that a recipient will be able to read the message: this can be based on a public key/certificate, a shared secret, a password, or even a key agreement protocol. You can have more than one recipient on a message, and you can mix and match types of recipient.

You can use CMSSignedDataGenerator to similarly send a verifiable message. If you want to sign and encrypt, the CMS structures are nestable/composable (but order could be important). There's also CMSCompressedDataGenerator and recently added CMSAuthenticatedData.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
byte[] process(bool encrypt, byte[] input, byte[] key)
{
    var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("Blowfish");
    cipher.Init(false, new KeyParameter(key));
    return cipher.DoFinal(input);
}

// Encrypt:
byte[] encrypted = process(true, clear, key);

// Decrypt:
byte[] decrypted = process(false, encrypted, key);
```

See: https://github.com/wernight/decrypt-toolbox/blob/master/dtDecrypt/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

JCE won't work for me because we want 256 bit strength and can't change the java configuration on the system to allow it. Too bad the Bouncy Castle doesn't have an API as high-level as JCE.

"Note however that bouncycastle consists of two libraries, the lightweight crypto library and the JCE provider interface library. The keysize restrictions are enforced by the JCE layer, but you don't need to use this layer. If you just use the lightweight crypto API directly you don't have any restrictions, no matter what policy files are or are not installed."
http://www.coderanch.com/t/420255/Security/AES-cryptoPerms-Unlimited-Cryptography

Comment: I'd rather drop the 256-bit requirement than the possiblity to use a high level interface and the possiblity to switch providers easily. I'm not a fan of the bouncycastle library, since it has too many flaws for my taste. Hence even if I'd use bouncycastle during developement I'd want to be able to switch it for something better once my code goes into production. Versatility is an important aspect when designing a crypto application. Locking down on a provider or set of crypto primitives can hurt you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Beginning Cryptography with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764596330) contains very helpful examples and explanations based on the bouncycastle library